# Get first n lines of new input when using tail -f

Tags: tail, logfile

I'm tailing a log file but I only want the first 3 lines of the new input each time somthing gets added to it.

I've tried `tail -f /var/log/webapps/app.name.com.error.log` and even piping output of tail -f to sed but neither of them worked the way I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know some content of the first line, you can pipe it with **grep** and **-A**

```
tail -f LGOFILE | grep "FIRSTLINE" -A 2
```

Comment: the first one only prints out the last 3 lines the file and then still prints out all the lines of each new input, i only want the first 3 lines of each new input.

Comment: Updated my answer... It worked in my case. Maybe you can go on from this.

Comment: No response? Maybe you grep'ed for the wrong string.

Comment: I got it to work by doing `|grep "#<.*Error:" -A 2` and it's working now.